# Как раскодировать двоичный код?

Tags: кодировка

Мне известны 9 символов латиницы и соответствующее им значение в двоичном коде, например: y - 10011010, t - 00101010, e - 01001010 и так далее. Как мне узнать кодировку? Т.е. значения остальных символов латиницы?

Comment: а точно такие значения? как-то странно - получается, что `e` находится между `y` и `t`. Попахивает криптографией.

Comment: я не знаю как закодирован алфавит. По сути, у меня есть двоичный код и я знаю с каких символов он состоит. Мне нужно узнать, как этот код перевести в символы, но я не знаю, как он образовался.

Comment: А исходная фраза и длина символа известны?

Comment: исходная фраза: ytrhjabkbz, в двоичном коде: 10011010   00101010   01001010   00010010   01010010   10000010   01000010   11010010   01000010   01011010

Answer (score 2):

Очень похоже на то, что байты нужно читать справа налево. В ключевой фразе есть `a` и `z` (кстати, в отзеркаленном виде соответствуют классическим ascii-кодам) - заполните промежутки и "отзеркальте".
Ну и ключевая фраза... весьма, весьма...

Answer (score -1):

в справочнике по кодировкам. В любом. ASCII код называется. Первая половина кодовой таблицы в восьмибитных кодировках.

Comment: по обычному справочнику не получается.

Comment: тогда при чем тут программирование, если это криптография?